# What package provides fonts for various languages?

Tags: fonts

I'm running web browsers on a minimal install of Ubuntu without the `ubuntu-desktop` package. It does not display some texts in other languages (for example, the languages links in Wikipedia).

As such, I conclude that no dependency pulled in those fonts. Which packages provides those?

**EDIT**
I already checked the [list of `ubuntu-desktop` dependencies](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-desktop), but there are only a few packages by the name of the languages themselves, and the rest I'm not sure what kind of fonts they package. (will edit this into question)

Comment: The naive way I can think is to do `apt search font` and then `grep` for the fonts you want.

Comment: @edwinksl, check my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on what language fonts you are willing to install.

If you want to install only the fonts comes with `ubuntu-desktop` package, you can get the list using

```
apt-cache depends ubuntu-desktop | grep 'font\|ttf' | cut -f4 -d ' '
```

The fonts packages installed by default in a Live Ubuntu 16.04 are (found by `grep`-ing [Ubuntu 16.04 manifest file](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.manifest))

```
fonts-arphic-ukai
fonts-arphic-uming
fonts-dejavu-core
fonts-freefont-ttf
fonts-guru
fonts-guru-extra
fonts-kacst
fonts-kacst-one
fonts-khmeros-core
fonts-lao
fonts-liberation
fonts-lklug-sinhala
fonts-lohit-guru
fonts-nanum
fonts-noto-cjk
fonts-opensymbol
fonts-sil-abyssinica
fonts-sil-padauk
fonts-stix
fonts-symbola
fonts-takao-pgothic
fonts-thai-tlwg
fonts-tibetan-machine
fonts-tlwg-garuda
fonts-tlwg-garuda-ttf
fonts-tlwg-kinnari
fonts-tlwg-kinnari-ttf
fonts-tlwg-laksaman
fonts-tlwg-laksaman-ttf
fonts-tlwg-loma
fonts-tlwg-loma-ttf
fonts-tlwg-mono
fonts-tlwg-mono-ttf
fonts-tlwg-norasi
fonts-tlwg-norasi-ttf
fonts-tlwg-purisa
fonts-tlwg-purisa-ttf
fonts-tlwg-sawasdee
fonts-tlwg-sawasdee-ttf
fonts-tlwg-typewriter
fonts-tlwg-typewriter-ttf
fonts-tlwg-typist
fonts-tlwg-typist-ttf
fonts-tlwg-typo
fonts-tlwg-typo-ttf
fonts-tlwg-umpush
fonts-tlwg-umpush-ttf
fonts-tlwg-waree
fonts-tlwg-waree-ttf
gsfonts
ttf-ancient-fonts-symbola
ttf-ubuntu-font-family
xfonts-base
xfonts-scalable
```

Or if you want to install fonts for a language, say `thai`, you can search using `apt cache search thai | grep 'font\|ttf'` and pick a font package from the list.

---

Here is another list of fonts available in Ubuntu repositories in [Community Wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fonts). It would be more convenient to choose from this list instead of `grep`-ing. But know that most of the package names there are starting with `ttf-` are now replaced with name starting with `fonts-`. So, you'll need to check `fonts-` version of a package name if `ttf-` doesn't work.

Comment: I already checked [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-desktop), but there are only a few packages by the name of the languages themselves, and the rest I'm not sure what kind of fonts they package. (will edit this into question)

Comment: @Oxwivi Can you provide some examples of the languages you might be interested in?

Comment: Those should be sufficient to be able to show you almost all languages in Wikipedia

Comment: I want to install fonts for UTF characters so none of them appears as boxes, and prefer to ignore any fonts solely for providing extra English typefaces.

Comment: Have you tried the solution given or commenting on your previous state? Even `fonts-noto-cjk` includes 100 MB of fonts from different languages

Comment: My point is, I already know `ubuntu-desktop` dependencies with fonts in their name (check the link). I'm asking if there's any package that only provides fonts enough to not show boxes on whatever webpage I load. I do not need the other, fancier typefaces.

Comment: Then you need to identify which language font is missing from those boxes and use the later solution. There are no ubuntu packages which provides fonts to targeting Wikipedia `boxes`.

Comment: @Oxwivi I haven't found a fully automated way of doing that. I suspect you would have to do it manually (and possibly still end up installing more than the minimally required fonts) like Anwar said.

Comment: Well, putting aside the fact that I might not even be able to tell what language that's appeared, only a few dependencies mention languages by name. For example, packages for languages like Thai, Tibetan, etc altogether only 13 languages are named. There's no packages for other languages, like the European ones, that Ubuntu also renders without issue.

Comment: I guess my only choice is to install whatever font dependencies are there.

Comment: @Oxwivi I've added another lists of fonts from official Wiki page. That will be more convenient to choose.

Comment: That list is dated (All, or at least most, packages starting with `ttf-` have been replaced with packages starting with `fonts-`.)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson thanks for the valuable comment. updated answer accordingly